# Enable immersive mode for navigation bar only

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

In my application I need to make status bar transparent (successfully implemented) and when phone have software navigation buttons show them only when user flick from the bottom and should disappear after X time (it is defined by system i believe).
I had looked many tutorials but all of them show how to enable immersive mode which cause to hide the status bar too.
This is the code that hide both status bar and navigation buttons:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.d("LogTag", "onFocusChanged");
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

I'm unable to make it work like the requirements, any idea?

If someone need code to make transparent status bar here is working code:

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = window.getAttributes();

winParams.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;

window.setAttributes(winParams);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Call it in `onCreate()` of the Actitivty.